# Why does my game display the wrong "required Android version" on Google Play?

Tags: android, unity, google-play

I'm porting a Unity game to Android, and I've set up the "Minimum API Level" in the Player settings to "2.3.3 (API level 10)".

However, on the store, it says "Requires Android: 1.6 and up".

On the Google Developer Console I didn't find this setting, so I guess the store is just trying to "guess" it examining the application, and failing.

Did I miss something?

Comment: is there something in your application that requires the higher android version?

Comment: @wes I can't even go below API level 9, so I guess that Unity itself requires that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have probably published your APK as Alpha or Beta. This is a known bug and Google Play store will incorrectly show "Requires Android: 1.6 and up". When you deploy your APK as production, it will show the correct number.

You can check your apk's minSdkVersion by the command-line tool `aapt` (inside sdk/platform-tools)

`aapt d badging game.apk`

or

`aapt l -a game.apk`

But you should put the correct setting to your manifest in any case:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="A" android:targetSdkVersion="B" />
```

Comment: Yes it was alpha!

Comment: @sm4, thanks! Also I see more mentions on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185204/google-play-beta-testing-and-publication-issues

Comment: "This is a known bug" If it's known then is it recorded in some google issue tracer? Where?

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Instead of editing it directly like Lestat tried, how about trying to set it programmatically, with the help of Unity.

```
PlayerSettings.Android.minSdkVersion = AndroidApiLevel10;
```

[Documentation for minSdkVersion](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.Android-minSdkVersion.html)

Comment: I no longer have access to that project, so I can't try that any more :/

Comment: @Lohoris :( I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

That is defined in the Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: The manifest doesn't have that line, so it could be that Unity "forgot" to add it... I'll have a look tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Oddly, it didn't work: still "1.6 and up"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you and/or your IDE (if you're using one) may have missed something. It's likely that there are elements in your project that are causing this.

Check for anything that may have been introduced in a later API. Also be sure your project is targeting the correct API level.